# App updates with hot reload, but not right when the button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

So my app looks like this:
[image]

You see the bar at the top? The one with "Venus", "Helado", etc... Well, that bar is supposed to let the user choose a "season", which would in turn change the "products". The products are cards that contain a phone case in it. My app works fine except for the fact that the "products" don't get updated when the user chooses another "season" (Venus, Helado, 1800s, etc). When I do hot reload, it does update... Say I select the "Season" of 1800s... the products won't change right away, I have to click on hot (or save). How can I do that automatically.

Here is the code, go to the `chooseSeasonBar` class to find the bar of buttons "Seasons".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TradingPage());

Season venus = Season('Venus', []);
Season helado = Season('Helado', [
  Product('Fresa Tuya', 'images/cases/strawBerryIceCream.png', 7, 7, 635),
  Product('Dementa', 'images/cases/mintIceCream.png', 4, 6, 742),
]);
Season year1800s = Season('1800s', []);
Season neonArt = Season('Neon Art', []);
Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo', []);
Season lente = Season('Lente', []);
Season joyasPreciosas = Season('Joyas', []);

List<Season> seasonList = [
  venus,
  helado,
  year1800s,
  neonArt,
  ritmo,
  lente,
  joyasPreciosas,
];

Season activeSeason = venus;

class TradingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          title: Text(
            'Relatable',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 3,
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 30.0,
              child: chooseSeasonBar(),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 750.0,
              child: ProductsOfSeason(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class chooseSeasonBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _chooseSeasonBarState createState() => _chooseSeasonBarState();
}

class _chooseSeasonBarState extends State<chooseSeasonBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            seasonList.forEach((element) {
              setState(() {
                element.color = 0xff808080;
              });
            });
            setState(() {
              activeSeason = seasonList[index];
              activeSeason.color = 0xff000000;
              print(activeSeason.name);
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: Text(
              seasonList[index].name,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(seasonList[index].color)), //grey
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: seasonList.length,
    );
  }
}

class ProductsOfSeason extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsOfSeasonState createState() => _ProductsOfSeasonState();
}

class _ProductsOfSeasonState extends State<ProductsOfSeason> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
            childAspectRatio: 1 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20),
        itemCount: activeSeason.products.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(activeSeason.products[index].caseName),
                Image(
                    image: AssetImage(activeSeason.products[index].imagePath)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Season {
  String name = '';
  List<Product> products = [];
  bool selectedTradingSite = false;

  Season(@required String name, List<Product> product) {
    this.name = name;
    this.products.addAll(product);
  }

  int color = 0xff808080; //grey
}

class Product {
  String caseName = '';
  String imagePath = '';
  int iPhoneAvailability = 0;
  int galaxyAvailability = 0;
  int averagePrice = 0;

  Product(caseName, imagePath, iPhoneAvailability, galaxyAvailability,
      averagePrice) {
    this.caseName = caseName;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.iPhoneAvailability = iPhoneAvailability;
    this.galaxyAvailability = galaxyAvailability;
    this.averagePrice = averagePrice;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is related to how to widgets are separated.

`chooseSeasonBar` and `ProductsOfSeason` are two stateful widgets that live inside another stateless widget called `TradingPage`. When a user taps on a button in the top bar, you call `setState` correctly, but it only updates the `chooseSeasonBar` widget which is why you don't see any change inside the product of season one. You need to find a way to rebuild/propagate the change in the `ProductOfSeason` widget. You can do that if you create a `stateful` parent widget and you call setState on it.

Here is how you can do that:

- Create a parent stateful widget and keep the `activeSession` data in it.
- Pass a callback to `chooseSeasonBar` that is called when the user taps on the button.
- When the callback is called `setState()`
- Pass the data to the `ProductSeason` widget.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TradingPage());

Season venus = Season('Venus', [
  Product('Test 1', '', 7, 7, 635),
  Product('Test 2', '', 4, 6, 742),
]);
Season helado = Season('Helado', [
  Product('Test 3', '', 7, 7, 635),
  Product('Test 4', '', 4, 6, 742),
]);
Season year1800s = Season('1800s', []);
Season neonArt = Season('Neon Art', []);
Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo', []);
Season lente = Season('Lente', []);
Season joyasPreciosas = Season('Joyas', []);

List<Season> seasonList = [
  venus,
  helado,
  year1800s,
  neonArt,
  ritmo,
  lente,
  joyasPreciosas,
];

class TradingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: TradingPageMainApp());
  }
}

class TradingPageMainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  TradingPageMainApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TradingPageMainAppState createState() => _TradingPageMainAppState();
}

class _TradingPageMainAppState extends State<TradingPageMainApp> {
  Season activeSeason = venus;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: Text(
          'Relatable',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 3,
                  blurRadius: 6,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                )
              ],
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 30.0,
            child: chooseSeasonBar(
              onSeasonChanged: (newSeason) {
                setState(() {
                  activeSeason = newSeason;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 750.0,
            child: ProductsOfSeason(season: activeSeason),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class chooseSeasonBar extends StatefulWidget {
  chooseSeasonBar({this.onSeasonChanged});
  final Function onSeasonChanged;
  @override
  _chooseSeasonBarState createState() => _chooseSeasonBarState();
}

class _chooseSeasonBarState extends State<chooseSeasonBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            seasonList.forEach((element) {
              setState(() {
                element.color = 0xff808080;
              });
            });
            widget.onSeasonChanged(seasonList[index]);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: Text(
              seasonList[index].name,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(seasonList[index].color)), //grey
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: seasonList.length,
    );
  }
}

class ProductsOfSeason extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductsOfSeason({this.season});
  final Season season;

  @override
  _ProductsOfSeasonState createState() => _ProductsOfSeasonState();
}

class _ProductsOfSeasonState extends State<ProductsOfSeason> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
            childAspectRatio: 1 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20),
        itemCount: widget.season.products.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.season.products[index].caseName,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                //Image(
                //    image: AssetImage(activeSeason.products[index].imagePath)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Season {
  String name = '';
  List<Product> products = [];
  bool selectedTradingSite = false;

  Season(@required String name, List<Product> product) {
    this.name = name;
    this.products.addAll(product);
  }

  int color = 0xff808080; //grey
}

class Product {
  String caseName = '';
  String imagePath = '';
  int iPhoneAvailability = 0;
  int galaxyAvailability = 0;
  int averagePrice = 0;

  Product(caseName, imagePath, iPhoneAvailability, galaxyAvailability,
      averagePrice) {
    this.caseName = caseName;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.iPhoneAvailability = iPhoneAvailability;
    this.galaxyAvailability = galaxyAvailability;
    this.averagePrice = averagePrice;
  }
}
```