# Flutter UI State only updates when I hot reload

Tags: android, flutter, dart, state, hot-reload

so heres how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

when i press add and input any data it saves it but doesnt update the ui so for some reason only when i **hotreload** it updates dashboarditems list to like this:

[image]

idk what causes this issues tho, any help would be helpful.

`code`: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/irskmRUy)

well i tried referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477648/app-updates-with-hot-reload-but-not-right-when-the-button-is-pressed) but this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

```
setState(() {
  dashboardItems.add(DashboardItem(name, url));
});
```

You are setting your state inside  `StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState)` block so it will be reflected in that block only.

So you need create function outside that current function for updating ui as following and call it in the add button pressed event.

```
void _AddDataAndUpdateUI(String name, String url) {
  setState(() {
   dashboardItems.add(DashboardItem(name, url));
  });
}
```